# ASP.Net MVC Post returns key-value pairs-how do I reference them in code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, key-value

I have a collection of key-value pairs that are being returned by post to which I am adding to a list.  I would like to append a value based upon the key.  In the example below, the for loop appends the key and calls a function (Boolean) that appends either a yes or no depending on the value.

What I would like to do is check the key name and IF the key begins with "chk" perform the loop below, ELSE IF, the key begins with anything else, I would like to append the value to the key.

I'm not sure how to reference the value of the key in code.  Thanks in advance.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < newKeys.Length; i++ )
        {
            sb.Append(newKeys[i] + ",\"" + Boolean(fc[newKeys[i]]) + "\",<br />");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is newKeys a generic Dictionary<>?

if so, you could...

```
        Dictionary<string, string> newKeys = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        newKeys.Add("chkOne", "some text");

        foreach (var s in newKeys)
        {
            if (s.Key.Contains("chk"))
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
```